# Change folder background color and text color in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: desktop-background, text

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and I want to change folder background color from default white to deep gray and text color from default black to white.
How can I do that operation?

Comment: Where exactly? In teminal emulators?

Comment: In file manager. Behind the folder icon.

Comment: Look this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/184914/38988