# Apply background image to nautilus in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, themes

I'm trying to apply a **background image to Nautilus** using one of the Ambiance themes (Ambiance Dark Red to be precise) in Ubuntu 14.04.

I followed [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/465908/how-to-change-background-of-nautilus-in-ubuntu-14-04) that indicates how to change the background color and [this other](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84130/how-do-i-theme-the-nautilus-background-image/) that says how to change the background image in an earlier version of Ubuntu.

I was able to successfully change the color but when I want to change the image a rather odd behavior occurs: the sidebar changes instead of the main part of the window:

[image]