# Set an backgroud image in ubuntu file manager

Tags: 16.04, graphics, gtk

In Ubuntu desktop file manager, we can change background color by editing and changing the basecolor value from gtk.css file from the location /usr/share/themes/Greybird/gtk-3.0/gtk.css.

Is any option available so that I can set an background image in Ubuntu file manager?

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate and the answer that you're looking for can be found at [How do I theme the Nautilus background image?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84130/how-do-i-theme-the-nautilus-background-image)

Just follow that link and the instructions are all there.

Comment: If you believe the question is a duplicate, you should flag it as such.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: @bashBedlam Kindly see this: http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/flag-posts