# How to set an image background for file manager (caja file manager)

Tags: 16.04, ubuntu-mate

I am using a Ubuntu-mate 16.04 and I use it everyday and I like it a lot. 
I am wondering if it is possible to display an image in the background of the file-manager.

I have taken a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84130) similar question but that one talks about `nautilus` not `caja`. This discussion talks about modifying the theme file.

My current theme file `index.theme` has the following contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=handsOn
Type=X-GNOME-Metatheme
Comment=

[X-GNOME-Metatheme]
GtkTheme=Ambiant-MATE
MetacityTheme=Ambiant-MATE
IconTheme=Humanity
GtkColorScheme=fg_color:#4c4c4c4c4c4c,bg_color:#a998a4daa4da,text_color:#3c3c3c3c3c3c,base_color:#c56abdf2b61d,selected_fg_color:#ee84e895f349,selected_bg_color:#8787a7a75252,tooltip_fg_color:#ffffffffffff,tooltip_bg_color:#000000000000
CursorTheme=DMZ-White
CursorSize=24
NotificationTheme=Coco
BackgroundImage=/home/vvy/Pictures/wall.jpg
```

I think I will have to add something to the line beginning with `GtkColorScheme=...` to put up an image in the background. Please help me with those `magic` keywords. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use Caja GUI:

*Edit → Backgrounds and Emblems* and then drag needed Pattern or Color

[image: Backgrounds and Emblems]

to the Caja window of interest. You can use your custom image by clicking on *Add a New Pattern* (image should allow patterning).

To reset the background setting you have to drag Reset pattern or color to the window.

Notes:

1. the background will be shown in *Icon View* and *Compact View*.
2. you have to set 'background-image' path by using `gsettings`:

   ```
   gsettings set org.mate.caja.preferences background-set 'true'
   gsettings set org.mate.caja.preferences background-color ''
   gsettings set org.mate.caja.preferences background-uri 'file:///usr/share/caja/patterns/dots.png'
   ```
3. also you have to set 'background-color' by using `gsettings`:

   ```
   gsettings set org.mate.caja.preferences background-set 'true'
   gsettings set org.mate.caja.preferences background-uri ''
   gsettings set org.mate.caja.preferences background-color '#E5E5E5'
   ```
4. to remove background programmatically use:

   ```
   gsettings set org.mate.caja.preferences background-set 'false'
   ```

Comment: So embarrassing! The option was **right there**. Its so nice that there is no need to fiddle with keywords. One additional detail, can we do alpha setting for the selected image?

Comment: I'm not sure about alpha setting, but you can try to adjust alpha channel in GIMP for PNG and GIF images :)

Comment: Done! Thank you for the answer.