# Changing background of ubuntu file manager

Tags: 20.04, filemanager, desktop-background

I am actually trying to change the background of the ubuntu file manager from white to some background picture (Not solid colors). I tried all the gnome and utility tweaks but they change it to solid colors like black, grey etc. But I want to insert a picture.
Is it even possible?
My ubuntu is 20.04.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the background of the file manager Nautilus to a picture. The colors and background of the application are controlled by the system GTK3 theme.

For (much) earlier versions, there was a [hack](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84130/how-do-i-theme-the-nautilus-background-image) through which one could set an image background to nautilus. An option was exposed in the user interface of Nautilus in its GTK2 versions.

Comment: Ok thanks @vanadium

Comment: Please "accept" the question that you feel answers your query best (you can upvote other good ones). This shows appreciation and also shows other readers useful answers can be found here.

Answer (score 0):

It **was** possible to do that on old Ubuntu Version.

```
1. Choose Edit -> Backgrounds and Emblems.
2. Click Emblem, and then click Add a New Emblem.
3. The Create a New Emblem dialog is displayed.
4. Type a name for the emblem in the Keyword text box.
5. Click Image.
6. In the dialog that is displayed, click Browse.
7. Choose an emblem, and click OK.
8. Click OK.
```

Comment: Then @Luca The Cat is it possible in the new version some other way?

Comment: This indeed obviously is not a valid answer for Ubuntu file manager. Moverover, emblems are little logo's you superimpose on the icon of the file, not the background. You may want to delete this answer.

Comment: Thanks @Lucas The Cat